# Trigger pop up confirmation box from edit to record?

Tags: process-builder, popup

I think the answer to this might be no, but just to confirm: is there any way that a process can include a pop up box to a user where they must confirm they want to proceed with triggering that process? Basically, I have a process that is triggered by a user adding a date to a field on a record, and I'd love to have a way to send the user a notice that by saving that edit, they'll be sending an email to that account (to help make sure they are ready for that email to be sent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kate,

Unfortunately, that's not available.
You can vote for this idea - https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l2cPAAQ.

Have you tried Visual Flow for this scenario. You can add a custom button to the page layout to call the Flow. In the flow, you can show a screen whether it's okay to send an email. If yes is selected, email can be sent. If No is selected, email won't be sent. You can call the Email Alert also from the Flow itself. To use the Email Alert in the Flow, check this - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_ref_elements_emailalert.htm&type=5

Please let me know if you have any additional questions.

Comment: Understood haha, thank you!! As I feared. Voted for that idea, thanks!